# Remover linha vazia de dentro de um texto com Java

Tags: java

Ao manipular um `xml` de retorno de um serviço, faço a seguinte manipulação no arquivo:

```
return xmlServico.replaceAll("job.coincidencia.vo.", "").replaceAll("RNSCoincidenciasMultiRamo_-", "").replaceAll("Coincidencia", "").replaceAll("<>", "").replaceAll("</>", "");
```

Porém, tais `replaces` geraram linhas vazias no meio do arquivo e, embora pareça algo simples, não estou conseguindo remover essas linhas vazias. Já tentei usar `.replaceAll(" ", "");` mas as linhas vazias continuam lá e isso ainda tira toda a formatação do `xml`.

Comment: Já considerou fazer um replace em todos os '\n' que estão em uma linha que não possui tags xml?

Comment: Eu acho mais simples usar uma lib específica para manipular o XML - em Java [existem várias](https://www.baeldung.com/java-xml). Fazer substituições na string é muito propenso a erros, há *corner cases* demais a serem tratados, coisa que uma lib consegue lidar muito melhor.

Comment: @AdrianoGomes fiz isso mas estava tirando toda a formatação do xml mas no fim acabei fazendo mais ou menos isso mesmo. Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo.

Comment: @hkotsubo Obrigado pela atenção, amigo. Acabei resolvendo de outra forma.

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi basicamente com um replace mesmo. Assim: `.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "")`

Obrigado pela ajuda de todos.